# Journey Builder Decision Split issues

Tags: journeybuilder

I'm trying to create a decision split within a Journey where if a lead status changes to ‘cancelled’ in Salesforce after the record's been entered into the Journey, the decision split will take the lead down a different path, which will ultimately exit them.

As I’m searching for a data value which has been updated after it’s been injected into a Journey, I understand I need to use Contact Data instead Journey Data. However, despite following this rule and creating the relevant filter in the decision split (Lead Status equals Cancelled) when undergoing some tests JB isn't acknowledging the decision split.

From my limited knowledge, because I'm using a Salesforce data as the entry source, the link between the Contact Key and the Lead ID in Contact Builder is automatically generated, so it should be able to process the request?

I’m aware that despite the change in SFDC the data in the DE which is created from the entry source isn’t being updated. How do I go about ensuring this update as I’m guessing this is likely to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you evaluating the status change in the Decision Split immediately after the change has been made? You made need to put a Wait Activity before the Decision Split and after you make the change. The data synchronized from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector can sync as often as every 15 minutes.

Check your Poll Schedule in Contact Builder.

[image: Poll Schedule]

To troubleshoot, I would begin by making the status change in the lead and see if the change if reflected in Marketing Cloud.